# Query regarding the default return type of a function in c++

Tags: c++, c, function, casting, return-type

A book says:

> If return type is not mentioned, it defaults to int.

Just to check this I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

print() {
    return 3.3;
}

int main(void) {
    double d = print();
    std::cout << d;

    return 0;
}
```

As expected I got output `3`. There's no problem.

I tried the following code which raised some confusion:

```
#include <iostream>

print() {
    char x = 97;
    std::cout << x;

    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    char c = print();
    std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting error here but I got output as `aa`.

---

**I've two doubts here:**

1. If the return type of `print` function is defaults to `int`, and as I am returning character variable, why I didn't receive any compilation error?
2. What exactly got returned by `print()`? As there is no error, clearly `print()` has returned `97`. But `x` was storing `a`. Then how `97` got returned?

Comment: The book and your compiler are very old. https://ideone.com/b9SKyu As for the second question, 97 is the ASCII code of 'a'.

Comment: A `char` is an integer type.  So the `print()` returns an int, then the int is stored in a char.  The `std::cout` interprets the `char` integer as a character.

Comment: `97` is the ASCII number for `a`. It is the same thing but interpreted differently if it is a `char` or an `int`.

Comment: C89, and possibly some implementations of pre-Standard C++, allowed omitting the return type. Standard C++ has never allowed it, and modern C no longer allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[In Visual Studio C++ since VS2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-c4430?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=This%20error%20can%20be%20generated,always%20issued%20as%20an%20error.)]

You have to specify the return type otherwise you will get a compilation "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int" *...Other systems generate just a warning.*

But, you ignored 1st issue intentionally. So let's assume `print()` returns `int` anyway...

> 1. If the return type of print function is defaults to int, and as I am
>    returning character variable, why I didn't receive any compilation
>    error?

- You can convert a 'char' type simply by assigning to an 'int'

> 2. What exactly got returned by print()? As there is no error, clearly
>    print() has returned 97. But x was storing a. Then how 97 got
>    returned?

- print() returns an `integer` that is a set of zeros & ones: with the decimal representation of 97 and with the ASCII representation of 'a'. Any variable is just a set of zeros & ones, that can be represented in different formats: decimal, hexadecimal, ASCII characters, etc.

--

If you want to see 9797 you have to write:

```
#include <iostream>

int print() // 1st issue: Add a return-type
{
    char x = 97; // The ASCII code of 'a' character
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x); // 2nd issue: Cast to int, or it will print 'a'

    return x; // You can convert a 'char' type simply by assigning to an 'int'
}

int main()
{
    char c = static_cast<char>(print());
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c); // Same 2nd issue
}
```

*"The C++ compiler treats variables of type `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` as having different types. Variables of type `char` are promoted to `int` as if they are type `signed char` by default, unless the /J compilation option is used. In this case, they are treated as type `unsigned char` and are promoted to `int` without sign extension." [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Type%20char%20is%20an%20integral,char%20as%20having%20different%20types.)*

Comment: What version of VS is this? I do not remember but 2007 used not to care about this.

Comment: @0x476f72616e I use VS2019

Comment: Do not worry I am just asking.

Comment: @0x476f72616e All versions before Visual C++ 2005 will compile the code. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-c4430?view=vs-2019#:~:text=This%20error%20can%20be%20generated,always%20issued%20as%20an%20error.).

Answer (score 1):

> *If the return type of `print()` is defaults to `int`, and as I am returning character variable, why I didn't receive error?*

The program asks the user to input something, it gets converted into an integer on assignment. In other words, if they input `a`, 97 is returned. Thus, when you try to store it:

```
char c = print();
//       ^^^^^^^ returns 97 and assigns to 'c'
```

**D-I-Y:** Try storing the values like: 65, 71, 98, etc. in `char` type, you'll get to know.

Also, you may get an error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘print’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Or, you'll get warned from the compiler (depending upon your compiler settings, this is what happened in my case):

```
warning: explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
```

---

> *What exactly got returned by `print()`? As there is no error, clearly `print()` has returned `97`. But `x` was storing `a`. Then how `97` got returned?*

This is called implicit conversion. An integer will get converted into a `char` when the type of lvalue is char.

Comment: *"you don't get an error, you'll get warned"* It depends on the compiler and its settings.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't allow functions with no return type. You end up getting a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Dev cpp. In Dev C++, you often don't get errors for functions with no return type but in editors like Visual Studio code if your function doesn't have any return type then either you will get a compilation error or void will act as default return type, not int.

Comment: I am using gcc ( version 6.3.0)